# Display thumbnail that user clicks as main image with Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am making a product thumbnail gallery, and wish to display the thumbnail that the user clicks as the main image. I am doing this with Angular, but I am fairly new to the framework.

product.html

```
<img src="{{mainImage}}">

<div class="thumbnails">        
        <img src="{{image1}}" (click)="changeMainImg()">
        <img src="{{image2}}" (click)="changeMainImg()">
</div>
```

product.ts

```
public mainImage;

public image1 = "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100";
public image2 = "http://via.placeholder.com/100x200";

public changeMainImg(event){
    this.mainImage = "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100";
}
```

For the part

```
this.mainImage = "http://via.placeholder.com/100x100";
```

I want this.mainImage to equal either image1, or image2, depending on which thumbnail is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the selected image to the function and assign it

```
<div class="thumbnails">        
        <img src="{{image1}}" (click)="changeMainImg(image1)">
        <img src="{{image2}}" (click)="changeMainImg(image2)">
</div>
```

and in TS

```
changeMainImg(image:any){
    this.mainImage = image;
}
```

**[`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/C0GKRDenkSoHurnJyitV?p=preview)**